# How to call component on onclick of node from react-d3-tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-d3

```
        class WorkflowDesign extends React.PureComponent {
          state = {};

          componentDidMount() {
            const dimensions = this.treeContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
            this.setState({
              translate: {
                x: dimensions.width / 2,
                y: dimensions.height / 2
              }
            });
          }


          render() {
            return (
              <div style={containerStyles} ref={tc => (this.treeContainer = tc)}>
                <Tree
                  data={this.props.data}
                  translate={this.state.translate}
                  orientation={'vertical'}
                  collapsible={false}
                  directed={false}
                  onClick={(nodeData, evtData) => {
                    if (nodeData.type === 'FLOW') {
                      this.props.getFlowNodeStartId(nodeData);
                    }
                    return;
                  }}

                  allowForeignObjects
                  nodeLabelComponent={{
                    render: <CollapsedBreadcrumbs data={this.props.breadcrumbtartNodeId} />,
                    foreignObjectWrapper: {
                      y: 24
                    }
                  }
                  }

                />
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
```

> I have tried with [react-d3-tee][1] but its not allowing me to call component inside onclick, So please help me out how to call component on onclick with some conditions, I have mention on the above code

**I wanted to call component on onclick which I have wrote onclick function with some condition**

```
      [1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-d3-tree
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't allow you? What happens when you click?

Comment: when I click on node if "nodeData.type === 'FLOW'" is true then it will dispatch one action, till now its ok . But I want call component "<CollapsedBreadcrumbs data={this.props.breadcrumbtartNodeId} />," as well when above condition is true

Comment: What do you mean you "want to call a component"? Components are not called, they are just rendered-  in a declarative way, not imperative.

Answer (score 1):

> That's how I do it:

```
    handleClick = (nodeData, evt) => {
       console.log(nodeData, evt);
     }
```

> in the Tree

```
    onClick={this.handleClick}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the props that you are looking for is `onNodeClick`

```
<Tree 
    data = {this.props.data} 
    onNodeClick = {this.handleClick.bind(this)} 
/>
```

and you can use it like:

```
handleClick(nodeData, evtData){
    // your code 
    if (nodeData.type === 'FLOW') {
         this.props.getFlowNodeStartId(nodeData);
    }
    return;
}
```

You can find out more in [the documentation here](https://bkrem.github.io/react-d3-tree/docs/interfaces/_tree_types_.treeprops.html#onnodeclick).